# How to use a background with rims and colored areas in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to have a layout in which I put other layouts (e.g. constrained layout) and those layouts should have rims and colored areas. So I guess I have to change the background but I do not know how. Here is a screenshot of my current fragment and I highlited the things that I would like to add:
[image]

Basically it should look somehow similar to [Desired layout](https://image.winudf.com/v2/image1/Y29tLmFwcHRpc3Quc21hcnRwb3Nfc2NyZWVuXzJfMTU0MjAwMTExMF8wNjE/screen-2.jpg?fakeurl=1&type=.jpg).

Here is the XML-layout file that I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_28sdp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_220sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_240sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.93"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"


        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_190sdp"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/navigation_button_language"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_31sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_31sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation_buttom"
        android:text="Dummy"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#121212"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_language"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3ssp"
        android:text="Dummy"
        android:textColor="#121212"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/navigation_button_language"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/navigation_button_language"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/navigation_button_language" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_240sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.447">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </ScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test Name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_QuantityText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:text="Quantity: "
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_Name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_Name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_QuantityNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_QuantityText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_QuantityText"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_QuantityText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_TableNumberText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:text="Table: "
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_QuantityText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_QuantityText"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_QuantityText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_TableNumberValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_TableNumberText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_TableNumberText"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_TableNumberText" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_message"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_markunread_24"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.221"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_TableNumberText" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_video"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_videocam_24"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton_message"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.827"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton_message" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:text="Message"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton_message"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton_message"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton_message" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Video"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton_video"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton_video"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton_video" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any idea how I can do that? I'd highly appreciate every comment and would be thankful for your help.

**Reminder**: Does nobody have any idea how I can do that? I have seen such layouts quite often so it should not be extremely unsual what I want to do.

Comment: You want to change the background color of that specific area where your constraint layout and it's items are being shown?

Comment: Thanks Kamal for your comment. Basically there are 2 tasks. 1) Add a rim to the constrained layout (the grey area) as can be seen in the posted link of the desired layout. 2) Change the background color of the yellow highlighted area in my screenshot.

Comment: @KamalNayan: Thanks Kamal for your comment. Any comments to my last comment? I'd highly apprciate every further comment from you.

Comment: For rim you can use padding .. in constraint layout and use a background colour according to your need ... This will make your rim

Comment: I have posted the answer. Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

**Make a drawable -> rim.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
     <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/space_lg"
        android:height="@dimen/space_lg"
        android:color="@color/#fff"
        android:dashGap="@dimen/space_sm" />

</shape>
```

and in the layout just use:

```
 android:background="@drawable/rim"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kamal for your answer and effort. Basically my desired layout link was just to show you how my layout should look like. I did not want to build exactly the same. Because of this I still really do not know how to implement the rim and the painted areas in my layout. I use the padding as you said but this does not create a rim. Also, you are using 2 CardViews. Why are you using them? For the colored areas?

Comment: Why do you use a cardView inside a ScrollView? Bascially the scrollView should not contain colored areas. What I basically wanted is just to add a rim to my layout and insert colored areas.

Comment: CardView is inside  constraint layout. And because in your expected layout I could see the elevation so I used CardView to get the desired output

Comment: Thanks Kamal for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Can I also do this without CardView? Because basically I just want to have the colored areas and not a CardView. Further, how can I create the rims? In your layout I also don't see the rims as in the desired layout. You said that I can use padding. I tried this but it did not create a rim.

Comment: And basically I have to admit that I do not understand your XML layout file at all. What do you put into the CardViews? Just some textViews into the first CardView, right? Why do you do this? And why is the CardView inside a ScrollView? I do not want the colored areas to be scrolled.

Comment: I tried to adopt your layout with the CardViews into mine but I could not manage to do it as the CardView created many errors. So is there not an easier solution to just color the areas? Maybe just have a colored area and not a CardView? The items do not have to be in a CardView (and to be totally honest, I do not see any advantages when having the items inside the CardView).

Comment: Thanks Kamal for your answer. Are you still intending to update your answer and if not do you have any comments on my last comments? I'd highly appreciate any further comment or update from you.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer, and by rim what I understand is a border. If not then I have posted a second layout without a border so you can pick what you need both layouts are without CardView. And sorry for the delay my exams were going on so it took more time. And feel free to ask if you need any alterations in the layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kamal for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. I still see no rim in your solution. With rim I mean something like a colored frame around the whole layout. On this link (https://image.winudf.com/v2/image1/Y29tLmFwcHRpc3Quc21hcnRwb3Nfc2NyZWVuXzJfMTU0MjAwMTExMF8wNjE/screen-2.jpg?fakeurl=1&type=.jpg) you can see a colored (grey/black) rim that servers as a frame around the layout. I do not see this in your solution. Do you know how I can include it?

Comment: I have updated the answer now it's having the rim . Let me know if you need some help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kamal for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. I have problems adopting your layout to my posted XML code? So what I want is to paint the area in my XML code (see Screenshot) with a color. You use a constraintLayout for painting right? I also tried to insert a constraintLayout as an additional element and painted it but the imageViews and textViews were overpainted by that. How can I adjust my XML layout to have these colored areas?

Comment: Futher, I still do not understand how you inserted the rim? As far as I understand you use 2 ConstrainedLayouts within each other. I also tried to do this in my XML code but this was quite messy.  I could not manage to choose the right layout widths and heights and constraines for the outer ConstrainedLayout (that I newly added) such that it looked good. Do you have any advice how to do this?

Comment: Without having a look at the code I can't suggest...... you can use other layouts if you have a problem using Constraint Layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kamal. Basically my code has been posted above in my question (the XML-layout file).

Comment: You can use Any layout instead of a constraint layout. The main approach is that you make a layout and give it a padding and set its background color (what you want to be of rim) and then inside that you again define a layout and in this, you define all your views like textview or something else.

Comment: Thanks Kamal for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it.  What you describe with any layout is how to make the rim, right? What about the colored areas? How is the basic approach there? Should I also use layouts within layouts to do this? Is there any alternative solution because I have problems with nesting layouts in each other. I use a ConstrainedLayout. Is there no element such that I can just define a colored area without using nested layouts?

Comment: I think this is the only way (having nested layout) to achieve rim as far as I know. If you find my answer helpful then kindly mark it as the correct answer and upvote it if possible so that it can help some needy in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kamal. I really appreciate it. Is there another way of making these colored areas instead of using nested layouts? Is there no such thing that can be inserted into the layout that just puts a color into the layout without using nested layouts?

Comment: Can make a drawable and will set it as the background of layout.... Will update the answer today using this method.

Comment: I have updated the answer , Kindly have a look.

Comment: Thanks Kamal for your answer and update. I really appreciate it. When using your suggested code I get 4 error messges in the XML layout file: "Cannot resolve symbol '@dimen/space_lg' ", "Cannot resolve symbol '@dimen/space_lg'", "The resource name must begin with a character" and "Cannot resolve symbol '@dimen/space_sm'"

Comment: These are dimensions , and you are getting error because you have not defined that.... Just replace that with the values you want. For example : android:width= 8dp and same for other attributes.

Comment: On top of that I am still wondering whether there is a solution for my second question about  creating colored areas within a layout without using a separate nested layout. Can I just add some elemnt inside a layout that paints a desired area? In your previous suggested solution you used nested layouts just for the purpose of creating colored areas and I am wondering whether there is also a solution without using additional nested layouts only for the coloring?

Comment: Thanks Kamal for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Regarding your rim solution: How can I fill the inside of the area with a certain color? So far the inside of your suggested layout element is just white while I can adjust the rim color.

Comment: You can use attribute android:background= "YOUR DESIRED COLOR". And this will give you the output as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort Kamal. I really appreciate it. Where exactly do I have to insert `android:background= "@color/colorGrey"`? When I put it into the constrained Layout I get a duplication error (as I have already defined the rim.xml as the background). When putting it inside the rim.xml file I do not get an error but the color is not shown at all. I tried to put the attribute both inside the stroke tags and inside the shape tags. But it did not help. The background remains white.

Comment: Here you can see the code `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:background= "@color/colorGrey">
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:height="@dimen/_220sdp"
        android:color="@color/colorBlue"
        android:background= "@color/colorGrey"
        android:dashGap="@dimen/_19sdp" />

</shape>`

Comment: Got you point ... if you want to have another background then you need to have a nested layout and set the background of inside layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kamal and your effort. I think that basically if I want to have a rim and colored areas there is no solution without nested backgrounds. So I guess I have to use this. Thanks for your tremendous help. I accepted and upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks @VanessaF Glad to help you.

Comment: Hi Kamal. It's me again. I had a look at your suggested code and solution and tried to use it. Unfortunately I have to admit that I don't like the solution at all. The big problem is that not only I can't change the background of the constraineyLayout when using your suggested code but also when the parent layout changes it's background, the background of the constrainedView also changes. So I can't have different background colors for the two layouts. Any solution for that problem?

Comment: If you don't know a solution for that problem of your suggested code with the rim.xml I would like to ask you 
what is the easiest way of adding another contrainedLayout as a parent to an already existing constrainedLayout without having to implement everything from the beginning?

Comment: Just add a constraint layout before the staring of existing constraint layout (means wrap the old constraint with new constraint layout ).

Comment: Thanks Kamal for your great help. Now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

drawable -> rim.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#0FECFF"/>
</shape>
```

Then, following your desired layout (in the picture), I made a simplified corresponding layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_left_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rim"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Left Side"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/v_left_background" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_navbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_Name">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order sheet"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Arrange products"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_3" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_okay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_navbar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_okay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Okay"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_left_background" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_right_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rim"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The screen then looks somewhat like this:

[image]

Constraint-wise:

[image]

(You can check the previews in the xml's `design` tab, I hope the constraints in the code are verbose enough for you to be able to follow)

**UPDATE**

Code without guideline:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_left_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rim"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.35" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Left Side"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/v_left_background" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_navbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_Name">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order sheet"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Arrange products"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_3" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_okay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_navbar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_okay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Okay"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_left_background" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_right_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rim"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/v_left_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dat Pham Tat. Can you just directly use pecentages for the two layouts instead of the guidlines (which makes it more complex) like `android:layout_width="0dp"  android:layout_height="0dp"  app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"  app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.15"`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any comments on my last comment? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.