# How to set size of layouts in Android as a percentage of the sceen size

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a ConstraintLayout  with an inner ConstraintLayout  and a inner linear layout in Android. Here you can see my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_235sdp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rim"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.93"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75">

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/innerConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/rim"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Inner Constrained Layout"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_okay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"
            android:text="Okay"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#121212"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.553"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem is that the two layouts have different proportions when being displayed on different screens (see screenshot):

[image]

This does not look good as depending on the used device the layouts look quite different regarding their proportions (width and height). Now my question is whether there is a way of just setting the layouts' width and height generally as a percentage of the screen size and thus make the proportions of the width and height of layouts independent of the screen size? Or how else would you design layouts sucht that their proportions between width and height is more or less independant of the screen size?

I'd appreciate every comment and will be happy if you share your experience on that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Now my question is whether there is a way of just setting the layouts' width and height generally as a percentage of the screen size*

It can be done using constarintLayout like this:

- Take any view, give it `android:layout_height="0dp"` - now it will respect your constraints, in additions add to it `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.15"`

Now the view got the height of 15% of the parent size.

- the same can be done for the width `android:layout_width="0dp"`
  together with `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"` and now your view will take 50% of your parent size.

You can combine those 2 like this:

```
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
 app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.15"
```

Now your view is both 15% of the parent Width and 50% the parent height, change those numbers and you can control your view size according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Tamir for your answer. I works quite well. I upvoted and accepted your answer. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
        ...
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_235sdp"
        ...
>
```

I assume in `@dimen/_235sdp` you have a value of `235dp`. If so, that line gives your `LinearLayout` fixed width of `235dp` on all devices, so you can't expect it to scale percentage-wise.

Try using a vertical [Guideline](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline) with percentage value and remove all other fixed sizes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/innerConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Inner Constrained Layout"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_okay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:text="Okay"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#121212"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the updated code I added a vertical guidline splitting the screen to 0.3 and 0.7, then I constrained the inner layouts against the guideline to keep the ratio. Now on any device, you should see the left inner layout taking always 0.3 of the width, and the right inner layout taking always 0.7 of the width.

Tip: try avoiding `ConstraintLayout` inside `ConstraintLayout`, it should be fully possible to constrain the inner content (i.e. TextView, Button) against the parent `ConstraintLayout` without breaking the layout.

Comment: Thanks Dat Pham Tat for your answer. I use the (for me) easier answer from Tamir with `v android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
 app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.15"`
Still I upvoted your answer as it contains valuable information.

Comment: One question regarding your tip. I have to use nested constraint layouts (even on more than 2 layers; so I have 3 times nested layouts) because I would like to have a rim on the outside of my sub-layouts and I want to have colored areas inside my layouts. For that purpose I have to use I have to use multiple nested Constraint Layouts (see my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68053716/how-to-use-a-background-with-rims-and-colored-areas-in-android)

Comment: I looked at the desired layout picture, it's quite complex, so I understand now why you need inner layouts. I added an answer that is close to the desired outcome with less wrapping layouts. Unfortunately for the colored area I needed an inner constraintLayout, as it would be difficult without it there.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem and to solve this problem, I divided each layer into two modes (mobile and tablet) (the Android system itself can recognize the sizes) and expanded both.
In this way, my work was more regular and changes in the next modes were easily possible for me.

my solution:

Make your resource like this.

res/**layout**/my_layout.xml

> layout for **normal screen** size ("default")

res/**layout-large**/my_layout.xml

> layout for **large screen** size

*If you do not know how to create a layout-large folder, all you have to do is create a folder with the same name in the Project Explorer path and place your layer there.
Then Android itself will automatically be placed in a separate folder for each layer you have in the Android Studio Live folder.
For example, the activity_main folder consists of two layers as shown below*

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Saman for your answer. Basically all the 3 screens I posed above are from tablets and they basically do not differ that much regarding the screen size but still the output looks quite different. So with your suggested approach I have to create a layout file for every possible screen size? So this means I would have more than 20 layout files for just one layout. Given that I have about 30 different fragments in my app this would lead to 30*20 = 600 layout files which is way to much.

Answer (score 0):

First of all simplify views tree. Use virtual layouts instead of nesting. You can use `Guideline`, `Flow`, attribute `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` or chains with weight for ConstraintLayout's children to use needed proportions.
This [article](https://medium.com/@sasanksunkavalli/android-constraintlayout-layout-constraintdimensionratio-33bd2293f34c) may help you

Another way is to create different [layout with qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes). Would be better to use single layout for better design management.

Comment: Thanks German for your answer. What do you exactly mean with qualifiers? In the link you sent me it is written that you can use them to distinguish between portrait and landscape mode. In my app I only use landscape mode. Further in your aticle it is said that I should not use hard coded sizes. I tackle this problem by using scalable size units from this library https://github.com/intuit/sdp